What is the encoding of this SHA256 hash in the Snakemake documentation?
I'm used to seeing SHA256 hashes printed as hexadecimal, but how is this one encoded?  u98a9cjsd98saud090923ßkpoasköf9ß32
This is from the Snakemake documentation, in this context:

A sha256 checksum can be compared as follows:
my_checksum = "u98a9cjsd98saud090923ßkpoasköf9ß32"

rule NAME:
    output:
        ensure("test.txt", sha256=my_checksum)
    shell:
        "somecommand {output}"


Is that not actually encoded at all and those are just the bytes of the hash?  I'd expect it to be a bytes object and not a string, though.

That is very weird. The tests that went in with the same commit show what is clearly a hexdigest of the content b"test": https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/e8735c1477a2a82110757ba86bbd1ccbcaf327ba/tests/test_ensure/Snakefile#L17-L24

Looks made up and invalid and like lacking documentation. I'd report it.

Added in snakemake #1651, it seems like a mistake or an oversight. Perhaps just someone mashing keys on a German keyboard layout?
In snakemake #2987 I've changed this example to:
9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08

Which is the sha256 hex digest of the bytes b"test".

it is likely broken, encoded by someone who doesn't know about encodings at all. The string should obviously be binary.  It can't be utf-8, since the "ß" would become a two-byte sequnce very little likely to be computed sequence in the hash.
So, try "latin1", where  "ß" is represented by the "\xcd" byte - it is a popular charmap encoding which includes that char, so there is a large chance it will work.
I.i. convert that string to a "bytss" object with checksum = my_checksum.encode("latin1") . That, and report a bug in the project that is using a text-string with non ASCII, non Escape chars to represent bytes.

I don't think anybody encoded anything there, it just looks made up. SHA256 produces 256 bits, i.e., 32 bytes. That string has 34 chars, almost only digits and ASCII lowercase letters. Highly unlikely to be real.
